# How can I pass parameters to inventory script from Ansible Tower Survey instead of configuration file

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-tower

What I managed to do at the moment, is to pass the parameters to the script via a configuration file.
Is it possible to pass them directly from Tower Template Survey?

The Python script is located in a SCM System.

```
myscript.py
config.ini
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access a survey variable the same way as any variable in ansible 
For example 
Passing a password via survey
`Answer varaible name` that you set can be used for getting value of the variable in the survey
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#create-a-survey

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I can access the variable in the python script as if it was an environment variable ?

Comment: you should be able to, I have used variable from the survey before, specifically password variable access it just like other variables `"{{ var_name }}"` where var_name is the `Answer variable name`

Comment: Yes, but that would work in the Playbook, but not in the python script !

Comment: Please mention the type of script in the question, I had to assume you are talking about yml script. Why not edit the script with an updated parameter using ansible before you execute it?